# Scene unsharp in Three.js when upgrading from r69 to r70

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm updating an old personal project that uses three.js, version r69.

The project currently looks like this: [sharp scene using three.js r69](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzaZD.jpg).

When I bump to the next version, r70, the whole scene gets unsharp. This seems to affect both models and background. The scene like this: [unsharp scene three.js using r70](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9Ggl.jpg)

I've read through the release notes for r70 thoroughly. There is a statement that says `WebGLRenderer: Refactoring and clean up`. Could it be related? What could be the cause?

(Please do not edit this post to inline the images as it hides the issue)

Comment: Looks like one image has anti-aliasing while the other doesn't. You probably just need to set a flag.

Comment: I agree that anti-aliasing is probably the culprit. The flag on WebGLRenderer enables hardware anti-aliasing, so you'll also ensure your browser supports it. http://webglreport.com/ Some browsers--such as Safari on iOS9--don't support hardware anti-aliasing, and will fall back to rendering a lower-quality image.